# Cannot increment value after successful check in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, post-increment

I have a variable inside a function (a React event handler) that counts the number of correct answers given by the user.

The function is the following:

```
handleFinishAssessment(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Assessment Finished");
    let correctAnswers = 0;
    let assessmentAnswersObjects = [];
    this.state.assessmentAnswers.map(answersArray =>
      answersArray.map(questionsAnswers =>
        questionsAnswers.map(
          questionAnswer =>
            (assessmentAnswersObjects = [
              ...assessmentAnswersObjects,
              questionAnswer,
            ])
        )
      )
    );
    assessmentAnswersObjects.map(assessmentAnswer =>
      this.state.userAnswers.map(
        answerGiven =>
          answerGiven === assessmentAnswer.answer &&
          assessmentAnswer.is_correct_answer &&
          console.log("Correct Answer") && // it's printed the number of time the check is successful
          correctAnswers++
      )
    );
    console.log("correct answers: ", correctAnswers);
  }
```

Basically the function prints "Correct Answer" every time the check guard encounters a correct answer (which happens), and should also increment the value of `correctAnswers` (which doesn't happen).

Why is that so?

How can I make this function work?

EDIT

[image]

Comment: are you seeing the `0` as the value of `correctAnswers`?

Comment: Yes, it's printing "correct answers: 0"

Comment: Could you show a log of assessmentAnswersObjects just to see the structure of your data?

Comment: I'll do it now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think in  your case by chaining the conditions like below, in `console.log("Correct Answer")` returns `undefined` so next condition which is `correctAnswers++` not gonna execute, remove the `console.log` and check it again

```
this.state.userAnswers.map(
    answerGiven =>
      answerGiven === assessmentAnswer.answer &&
      assessmentAnswer.is_correct_answer &&
      //console.log("Correct Answer") && this will return undefined and not going to execute next condition
      correctAnswers++
  )
```

Comment: Yep, that is the case. Would have never work that out by my own. Thanks :)